# Phoenix: Running mix ecto.create Error Compiling Ranch Dependency

Tags: phoenix-framework, rebar3

I'm trying to go through the Up And Running tutorial on the Phoenix framework site. I have the following setup :

- macOS 10.14.5
- Phoenix 1.4.6
- Elixir 1.8.2
- Erlang/OTP 22

I create the project with the `mix phx.new` command. I get prompted to fetch and install the dependencies. I type `Y`. The dependencies get fetched and installed successfully.

I go to my project directory and enter the following command :

```
mix ecto.create
```

The following error appears :

> (Mix) Could not compile dependency :ranch, "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/mark/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths "/Code/hello/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin"" command failed.
>
> You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ranch", update it with "mix deps.update ranch" or clean it with "mix deps.clean ranch"

I get the same error if I run `mix phx.server`.

If I run `mix deps.clean ranch` and `mix deps.update ranch`, it lists the following unchanged dependencies:

```
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
Unchanged:
  connection 1.0.4
  cowboy 2.6.3
  cowlib 2.7.3
  db_connection 2.0.6
  decimal 1.7.0
  ecto 3.1.4
  ecto_sql 3.1.3
  file_system 0.2.7
  gettext 0.16.1
  jason 1.1.2
  mime 1.3.1
  phoenix 1.4.6
  phoenix_ecto 4.0.0
  phoenix_html 2.13.2
  phoenix_live_reload 1.2.0
  phoenix_pubsub 1.1.2
  plug 1.8.0
  plug_cowboy 2.0.2
  plug_crypto 1.0.0
  postgrex 0.14.3
  ranch 1.7.1
  telemetry 0.4.0
```

So ranch has been compiled. But when I run `mix ecto.create` again, I get the same error about being unable to compile dependency :ranch.

I did an Internet search to see if anyone else had the same issue. Every issue someone had with `mix ecto.create` involved creating database users. No one else had an issue with ranch.

What do I have to do to get the Up and Running tutorial running properly?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: No I didn't. The issue is still there in Phoenix 1.4.

Comment: The steps the op posted work without error for me on OSX 10.13.6, Phoenix v1.4.0, Elixir 1.6.6 (compiled with OTP 19), and Erlang/OTP 20.  Although, the list of dependencies is different now.

Comment: This issue seems to relate to a fairly specific combination of Elixir and OTP.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem under Ubuntu, and the issue was that the ~/.configure folder was unreadable by my current user. Changing the owner and group on that folder and it's contents solved the problem for us.

I was able to recreate this problem under MacOS, using Elixir 1.7.4 and Erlang 20.1 by changing the permissions on my ~/.config folder to 600. Setting the permissions back to 755 allowed the compile.

Comment: On the Mac, there is a ~/.config folder. My user is the owner of that folder. I tried going through the tutorial again, running macOS 10.14.5, and the error still persists.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I was able to recreate this problem under MacOS, Elixir 1.7.4, and Erlang 20.1 by changing the permissions on my ~/.config folder to 600. When I do this, I get the ranch compile error. Changing the permissions back to 755 allows compilation of ranch. What are the permissions on your ~/.config folder?

Comment: The permissions are drwxrwxr-x. I'm not sure what the numerical equivalent is.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk okay. Then that isn't the issue. The only other things I've seen are installing erlang-parsetools and erlang-dev. How did you install Erlang?

Comment: @philosodad It's been a year since I asked this question so I'm not exactly sure how I installed Erlang. I either installed it using Homebrew or from source from the Erlang site.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk if with homebrew I'd try updating/upgrading Erlang. I haven't been able to reproduce this error with any version of Erlang I have installed without messing around with the ~/.config file so I'm at a bit of a loss. I know it's been a while since you asked but I hate to think that you can't even mess around with Phoenix because it won't install!

Comment: @philosodad I updated the question with my latest attempt using Erlang 22 and Phoenix 1.4.6. I appreciate the help, but I still get the same error running mix.ecto.create.